# Si el explode viene vacio no hacer acción

Tags: php, html, condiciones

Buenas estoy guardando datos un una base de datos, pero me encuentro con un problema. Traigo un explode con una galeria de imagenes. El problema es que tiene que haber posisibilidad de no poner galeria, entonces mi intención, es que si no pongo ningún archivo no me genere filas en la tabla, pero es que aunque no ponga datos me llega esto:

```
array:1 [▼
  0 => ""
]
```

Yo intento de este modo, pero sin éxito:

```
$galeria  = $request->input('galeria');
$laGale = explode(",", $galeria);

if($laGale == " "){

}else{
  foreach($laGale as $gale){
   $addGaleria = new Galeria;
   $addGaleria->product_id = $idProductoRecienGuardada;
   $addGaleria->foto = $gale;

   $addGaleria->save();
  }
}
```

Comment: Si correcto @BetaM , pero como me devuelve lo de `0=->""` no tengo forma de hacerlo

Comment: Quizas tendria que comprobar si es null $galeria más bien no?

Comment: Correcto, tenia que comporbar `$galeria` que es el input, ahora si me funciona!

Comment: Considera publicar tu solución entonces, además esto: `""` no es lo mismo que esto: `" "`

Answer (score 0):

Bien lo que había que hacer es comprobar `$galeria` que trae el valor del input, de este modo al ser `null` o no, hago una cosa u otra.

```
if(!is_null($galeria)){
   foreach($laGale as $gale){
     $addGaleria = new Galeria;
     $addGaleria->product_id = $idProductoRecienGuardada;
     $addGaleria->foto = $gale;

     $addGaleria->save();
    }

}
```